# How do I fix 404 error on Github Pages for a personal page I'm creating

Tags: github, github-pages, github-actions

I tried to access my GitHub page:https://adityakm24.github.io/ But it shows 404 pages not found. I looked for many tutorials online but couldn't come up with a proper solution. Adding /Index.html doesn't work either. But I am sure about adding the index.html in my repo and index.html file is in the master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://adityakm24.github.io/ means a [User page](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites), for a GitHub repository named `<user>.github.io` at, in your case, https//github.com/adityakm24/adityakm24.github.io

Make sure you have [selected a Source in the settings of that repository](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source): it should be `master` by default.

And your file must be `index.html`, not `Index.html` (it is case sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose the branch properly in the settings page as shown below

[image]

Go to settings>manage access>manage

Answer (score 1):

Here I can point out two reasons why it is not coming up

1. Provide the proper 'homepage url' in your package.json. This is a very important step. Follow this convention- "https://{username}.github.io/{RepoName}/". Anything other than this will give 404 error.
2. Go to your github repository and select the gh-pages branch.(No other branch will work)